# The quote about implicitly-declared copy constructor is unclear on logic

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the form
>
> > X::X(const X&)
>
> if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type M (or array thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type `const M&` or `const volatile M&`
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form
>
> > X::X(X&)

I think about this sentence, the logic can be transformed as that:

> It's my box if each **red** card in this box has a shape of circle, otherwise it's jack's.

So, I have searched this box and I found there's no any red card in this box at all. Therefore,Is this box is mine or jack's? I think it's an ambigous proposition. It's a typically logic issue.

```cpp
class A{
  int b;
};
int main(){
   A a;  //A::A(A&) or A::A(A const&) ?
}
```

I.E., the questions also can be transformed to:

```
//For this condition, A is either 0 or 1, Now I set A = 2
 if(all(A) == 0){
   then A belong to you
 }else {
   then A belong to mine
 }
when there's no A in the set.  A belong to mine?
```

I think modify the sentence like this:

> if **exists** any potentially constructed subobject of a class type M (or array thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter **is not** of type const M& or const volatile M&, the implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the form:
>
> > X::X(X&)
>
> otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form:
>
> > X::X(const X&)

That would be more clear.

```cpp
if(exsit(A)!=1){
  then A will belong to you
}else{
  A will belong to mine
}
```

So, for `A`, as long as exist `A` that value of the A is not 1, it will be the first branch, otherwise it will be the second branch, It does not exist a value of A that make there's no branch can match it or ambigours.

Comment: @cigien The question is, for `class A{ int b;}`, the implicitly-defined copy constructor would be `A::A(A&)` ?

Comment: I find "*if each .. has*" more to the point than "*if any .. has not*" here, but it's just a matter of style and preference.

Comment: @dxiv It's like  an question, `A` is either `0` or `1`, `if 0 { A will belong to you.}else{A will belong to mine}`, Now the value of A is 2,Does A belong to you or mine?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Your rewrite starting with "*if exists any ...*" is an exact negation of the original "*if each ...*", so the two formulations are entirely equivalent.

Comment: @dxiv I don't think so, please note these emphasized wording in my rewriting, such as if exists a base subobject, its copy constructor is `Base::Base(Base&)`, so it satisfy the requirement that is not of type const M& or const volatile M&, so, the copy constructor form will be `X::X(&)`

Comment: All I am saying is that your "*if(exist non-P) B else A*" is entirely equivalent to the original "*if(all P) A else B*" and I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: @dxiv if there's no `P` at all?

Comment: Then `all P` is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, I will look at the link later. But, for this question `It's my box if each red card in this box has a shape of circle, otherwise it's jack's.`. there's no any red card in the box, only orange, blue, black and so on but not red, Is it my box or jack's box?could you please answer this question?

Comment: It's yours. For Jack to claim the box, he would have to produce a red card that's not a circle. But he has no such card to show.

Comment: @dxiv okay, thanks, if you could leave a answers, maybe someone who have the same questions will appreciate you.(However, It's not the common logic on daily, due to it's a vacuous truth, I can't say nothing ;-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two formulations are entirely equivalent. The standard statement is of the form `if(all P) then A else B`, while the proposed re-statement is simply `if(exist non-P) then B else A` which is logically the same.

The question raised boils down to how this works when the set `all P` is empty i.e. class `X` has no "*potentially constructed subobject of a class type (or array thereof)*". In that case `if(all P)` is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), so case `A` applies. In other words, the implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class `X` with no potentially constructed subobjects of a class type (or array thereof) has the form `X::X(const X&)`.

As a side note, the notion of "*vacuous truth*" may sound a bit like logic sophistry, but it is often used in different disguises. For a C++ example:

```
bool IsAllPositive(vector<int> const &v)
{
    for(auto n : v)
        if(n <= 0) return false;
    return true;
}
```

This returns `true` if the vector is empty, and indeed `IsAllPositive` is vacuously true in that case.

Comment: Suggestion: modify `potentially constructed subobject` to `potentially constructed subobject of class type M which...`, because `int a` is also a `potentially constructed subobject`.

Comment: Exactly, `the notion of "vacuous truth" may sound a bit like logic sophistry` +1, such as "all the cell phone in the room are bigger than earth" even true if there's no cell phone in the room at all. It's so weird.

Comment: @jackX I edited the missing part in ("subobject *of a class type (or array thereof)*"). That does not include the "*which*" clause since, in the context, that's immaterial once no qualifying subobjects exist. As for `int`, fundamental types are certainly not "*of a class type*".

Comment: Similarity issue: If moscow is the captial of American, then you couldn't have went to moscow but haven't wen to American, otherwise..., For this proposition, if I have found moscow is in Russia, then I can say the  `if` is false, hence the `otherwise` branch works, Right?

Comment: `If moscow is the captial of American, then ...` You can replace `...` with *anything* and the logical implication will be true. This is not only "*similar*" but actually the *same* as "*vacuous truth*". That said, I think you are splitting hairs that no longer have much anything to do with C++ at this point.

Comment: However, I can find moscow in Russia in the set of earth, so "then" will no be true, I'm confused about this. If there's no moscow, that is, the element is empty, then it's a vacuous true. I think

Comment: Not sure I follow. The truth value of the *implication* `if(P) then Q` is a different matter than the individual truth values of `P` and `Q`, I can only suggest you take this kind of question next door to [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), at the risk of being marked as a duplicate of [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474054/), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699638/), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48161/), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/) etc.

Comment: Thanks,I'm studing  these linked knowledges. It make me so headache